# Angular 2 unit test must call whenStable multiple times when nesting ngModel elements

Tags: angular, testing

I am well aware of this bug here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10148

Which mentions the need to call `fixture.detectChanges();` then a `fixture.whenStable()`.

However, when I start nesting elements that each makes a usage of the ngModel value accessor provider, I have to call these two methods in a loop.

Is there a different way to do this? It doesn't seem super efficient and I constantly need to edit this function. I could simplify this with a recursive method to prevent duplication, but that's not the question.

```
export function bugWhenStable(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>): Promise<any> {
    let def = new Promise(resolver => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
            fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                fixture.detectChanges();
                fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                    resolver();
                });
            });
        });
    });

    return def;
}
```

My components do something like this:

```
<wm-comp1 [(ngModel)]="value"></wm-comp1>
```

Which in Comp1 I have

```
<wm-comp2 [(ngModel)]="value"></wm-comp2>
```

etc.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem - did you ever find a better approach?

Comment: @wags1999 nope, still the same issue. I have noticed running multiple times whenStable does not significantly slows down my tests... however, it's quite ugly. Creating a testBed and components are the slowest parts.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question, and thanks everyone for answering it, you saved my day  :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not using `async/await`

```
it('should do whatever', async(async() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  await fixture.whenStable();
}));
```

Comment: The problem is that you have to call it multiple times. You made it pretty, but you still have to loop it. I mentioned that in my bug above.

Comment: Yes, you could warp it in a util function, to loop multiple time

Comment: I understand that, but my main question was how to avoid that. How to avoid having to call detectChanges as many time as you have nested ngModels.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried returning the promise to the the next then fn? this will makeit waits until it gets resolved. I tried it once in my specs and worked perfectly. looks cleaner.

```
export function bugWhenStable(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>): Promise<any> {
  let def = new Promise(resolver => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable()
      .then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        return fixture.whenStable();
      }).then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        return fixture.whenStable()
      }).then(() => {
        resolver();
      });
  });

  return def;
}
```

Also some people doing it like, but I never tried that.

```
export function bugWhenStable(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>): Promise<any> {
  let def = new Promise(resolver => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    resolver();
  });
});

return def;
}
```